# Field that contains all the strings of an array

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, entity-framework, mongodb-.net-driver

How to make the following Entity framework query in MongoDB C# driver?

*Get all objects that contains all keywords from the filter - in its name property*

```
var keywords = filter.Split(' ');
_context.Businesses
            .Where(b => keywords.All(s=>b.Name.Contains(s)))
            .ToList();
```

I've tried to excute the same query on mongo but I get that the filter is unsupported

```
_collection.Find<Business>(b => keywords.All(s => b.Name.Contains(s))).ToList();
```

The exception

> An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in
>   MongoDB.Driver.dll but was not handled in user code
>        Additional information: Unsupported filter: All(value(System.String[]).Where({document}{Name}.Contains({document}))).

**Solution**

I've changed the query as M.Wiśnicki suggested

```
return _collection.AsQueryable<Business>().AsEnumerable().Where(b => keywords.All(keyword => b.Name.Contains(keyword))).ToList();
```

Comment: What is wrong with this code?

Comment: @M.Wiśnicki added the error to the question

Comment: Try use `AsEnumerable()` before `Where`

Comment: @M.Wiśnicki you are right, I've used AsQueryable + AsEnumerable and now it works. Please add it as answer

Comment: You have to use strongly-typed collection, i had similar problem, im not sure what i use `AsQueryable` or `AsEnumerable ` , but im sure not both. Try use `AsQueryable` only

Comment: @M.Wiśnicki with AsQueryable only it fails the same way. And I can't access AsEnumerable without AsQueryable

Answer (score -3, accepted):

In MongoDB you need use strongly-typed collection when you call LINQ queries. So need to use `AsEnumerable()`, this return output as `IEnumerable<out T>` and you will be able use LINQ. Your query should look like

```
var results = Businesses.AsEnumerable().Select(x => x.ToLower())
            .Where(x => keywords.All(x.Contains));
```

Answer (score 4):

Proposed answer will be ok, but this way you get all data to client, the query could be executed directly on `MongoDB`:

```
var results  = _collection.Find(Builders<Business>.Filter.Not(
                   Builders<Business>.Filter.ElemMatch(
                            x=>x.keywords,
                            k=>!k.Name.Contains(s))));
```

It's a little bit tricky, because we filter all values that not (not contain s), but it works. 
If you don't have a huge amount of data it's ok to query `Enumerable` as already proposed.